# Amazon S3 Rename Objects Using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am interested if there is a way to rename a folder(Object) from a bucket in Amazon S3, using Objective C.

From what I have read it is not possible, instead I found that I should create a new directory and copy each item from the original one to the new one and at the end I should remove the original directory(Object).

Can anyone provide an example for any of the cases?

**UPDATE 1:**

Thought about doing something like this, to replicate the same object inside the same bucket but I get an error:

`The request failed. error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSServiceErrorDomain error 11.)`

```
- (void)test{

    AWSS3 *s3 = [AWSS3 defaultS3];
    AWSS3ReplicateObjectRequest* replicateRequest = [AWSS3ReplicateObjectRequest new];
    replicateRequest.bucket = kAmazonS3Bucket;
    //folder to copy the .txt file from
    replicateRequest.key = @"backup/folder2/file.txt";
    //original .txt file location
    replicateRequest.replicateSource = @"backup/folder1/file.txt";
    replicateRequest.ACL = AWSS3ObjectCannedACLPublicReadWrite;

    [s3 replicateObject:replicateRequest
      completionHandler:^(AWSS3ReplicateObjectOutput * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
          if(error){
              NSLog(@"The request failed. error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
          }
      }];

}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is the implementation that I use to delete files from Amazon, note that the dele folder is not working.

```
/**

 Use this function to delete item at path inside a bucket
 @autor Daisoreanu Laurentiu
 @param filePath The path for the file that should be removed. Example of path: `backup/test.txt`

 */
-(void)deleteObjectAtPath:(NSString *)filePath
               completion:(void (^)(BOOL success))completionBlock{

    [self setupAmazon];

    AWSS3 *s3 = [AWSS3 defaultS3];
    AWSS3DeleteObjectRequest *deleteRequest = [AWSS3DeleteObjectRequest new];
    deleteRequest.bucket = kAmazonS3Bucket;
    deleteRequest.key = filePath;

    [s3 deleteObject:deleteRequest
   completionHandler:^(AWSS3DeleteObjectOutput * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
       if(error){
           NSLog(@"The request failed. error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
           completionBlock(NO);
       }
       else{
           completionBlock(YES);
       }
   }];


}
```

Comment: can you enable debug logs and see whats the response from the service?

Comment: The error you recieved is Access denied which means you dont have the right permission, Make sure that the permissions are right Replicate should work for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these REST API examples:

**Copy object:**

```
PUT /destinationObject HTTP/1.1
Host: destinationBucket.s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-copy-source: /source_bucket/sourceObject
x-amz-metadata-directive: metadata_directive
x-amz-copy-source-if-match: etag
x-amz-copy-source-if-none-match: etag
x-amz-copy-source-if-unmodified-since: time_stamp
x-amz-copy-source-if-modified-since: time_stamp
<request metadata>
Authorization: authorization string (see Authenticating Requests (AWS Signature Version
    4))
Date: date
```

**Delete object:**

```
DELETE /ObjectName HTTP/1.1
Host: BucketName.s3.amazonaws.com
Date: date
Content-Length: length
Authorization: authorization string (see Authenticating Requests (AWS Signature Version
    4))
```

More information here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectDELETE.html

Comment: Already sowed the API but I am interested how can this be done in Objective C.Also I have the delete method, I will upload it here